Tstringlist fails to iterate
I am trying to import a CSV file via a TStringlist.
procedure TOrder_import.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
F: textfile;
ST : Tstringlist;
datas : string;
i : integer;    
 begin
 try
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  ST:= Tstringlist.Create;
  order_entry.OpenDialog1.Execute;
  AssignFile(F, order_entry.OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(F);
  read(F, Datas);
  st.CommaText := (datas);
  ExtractStrings([',' ],[], Pchar(datas), ST);
  begin
    for i :=  st.Count -1 downto 0 do
    begin
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[4]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[12]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[22]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[46]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[57]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[60]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[62]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[72]);
     Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[88]);
     ProgressBar1.StepIt;
     // readln;
    end;
  end;

  finally
  ST.Free;
  ShowMessage('Sucess!!')
 end;

end;

This code compiles and runs without errors, however it fails to iterate to the next string in the TStringlist.
I tried putting a readln at the end of the loop but then the program crashed with

i/o error 6

Why is the TStringlist not iterating through it's strings?

ST[4] accesses the 4th item in the list. You nowhere use the loop's variable i and nothing is "moved" automatically. If you wanted particular characters out of one line then you have to do ST[i][4].

@AmigoJack thank you for your comment. I tried doing as you suggested, however it gave me random characters and only one character per line in the TMemo. To be clear, I am pulling certain fields out of the CSV file and am not using the rest.

Well, you're not doing anything to move to the next line (whatever that means in this context). What is st, and where is it coming from? You need to add more context for anyone to help you.

I apologize and will edit the question. ST is the Tstringlist and yes, my question was how to move to the next line

What does the CSV itself look like, and what do you want the Memo to look like after you load the CSV? These are the kinds of details you need to provide in your question. I'm guessing that you need to loop through the TStringList parsing each line into another list, and then copy values from that 2nd list into the Memo.

@RemyLebeau, please bear with me if I'm a little dense, but why does it matter what the CSV looks like? The memo is supposed to have the columns mentioned displayed in order- the Memo is basically a test to make sure we're reading it right (which we obviously aren't) and will be replaced by a DB.

Also I forgot to mention that it is already parsed. the parsing works fine I just need to figure out how to advance through the records - which I thought a For loop would do automatically

However, I can post the complete procedure if it helps... just thought I wouldn't clutter up the question with unnecessary code.

Also, off topic, but very important: If ProgressBar1.Position := 0; or Tstringlist.Create raises an exception, you'll run the dtor on a random pointer: ST.Free. Then anything can happen. For instance, your app may incorrectly send a $50M invoice the week later (instead of the intended $3 invoice). You must always, always, put the try on the line immediately after the ctor-assignment line: Frog := TFrog.Create; try { use Frog } finally Frog.Free; end;.

@KenWhite, I apologize that my post was unclear. I have edited it and attempted to correct my mistakes. And the question I was asking from the beginning, as the title suggested, is why the TStringlist is not iterating through it's strings. Thank you for repeating my question in your comment. Perhaps that will make it more clear. If there is anything else I could improve in the question please let me know as I am not the smartest programmer around. Thank you.

@AndreasRejbrand, thank you for your comment. I will correct that

Use TStringList.ReadFromFile


Why is the TStringlist not iterating through it's strings?

Because you didn't write your code to do that.  You are extracting specific (and apparently random) strings from the TStringList, completely ignoring the loop index variable.

The memo is supposed to have the columns mentioned displayed in order- the Memo is basically a test to make sure we're reading it right (which we obviously aren't)

If you are trying to display the column names from the 1st line, then try something more like this:
procedure TOrder_import.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F : TextFile;
  // Reader : TStreamReader;
  ST : TStringlist;
  dataS : string;
  i : integer;    
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;

  if not order_entry.OpenDialog1.Execute then
    Exit;

  AssignFile(F, order_entry.OpenDialog1.FileName);
  try
    Reset(F);
    Readln(F, dataS);
  finally
    CloseFile(F);
  end;

  { alternatively:
  Reader := TStreamReader.Create(order_entry.OpenDialog1.FileName);
  try
    dataS := Reader.ReadLine;
  finally
    Reader.Free;
  end; }

  ST := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ST.CommaText := dataS;
    { or, NOT both:
    ExtractStrings([','], [], PChar(dataS), ST); }

    ProgressBar1.Max := ST.Count;
    ProgressBar1.Step := 1;

    for i := 0 to ST.Count-1 do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[i]);
      ProgressBar1.StepIt;
    end;
  finally
    ST.Free;
  end;

  ShowMessage('Sucess!!')
end;

On the other hand, if you are trying to display the actual data values for specific columns in the file, then try this instead:
procedure TOrder_import.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileST, LineST : TStringlist;
  i : integer;    
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;

  if not order_entry.OpenDialog1.Execute then
    Exit;

  FileST := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FileST.LoadFromFile(order_entry.OpenDialog1.FileName);

    ProgressBar1.Max := FileST.Count;
    ProgressBar1.Step := 1;

    LineST := TStringList.Create;
    try
      for i := 0 to FileST.Count-1 do
      begin
        LineST.CommaText := FileST[i];
        { or:
        LineST.Clear;
        ExtractStrings([','], [], PChar(FileST[i]), LineST); }

        if LineST.Count > 88 then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[4]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[12]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[22]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[46]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[57]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[60]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[62]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[72]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LineST[88]);
        end else
        begin
          //...
        end;
        ProgressBar1.StepIt;
      end;
    finally
      LineST.Free;
    end; 
  finally
    FileST.Free;
  end;

  ShowMessage('Sucess!!')
end;


There are so many things wrong with the code you posted that it's hard to know where to start pointing them out.

You use try..finally incorrectly.
You read only once from the file, because the read is not inside a loop.
You never check for the end of the file (which doesn't matter much because of the previous issue).
You loop through the TStringList.Count, but never use the index variable for anything, which means the loop does nothing. (You also loop backward for no apparent reason, which doesn't make much sense. If you have such a reason, then that's not an issue.)
You access elements by index in the ST without making sure they exist first (no error handling for short lines).
You're using 1980s style file I/O instead of something more modern like a TFileStream.
Not an error, but wasted keystrokes and space - you have a needless begin..end block outside your for loop (the one right below ExtractStrings, whatever that is doing - CommaText separates the string on the comma for you).

It would be much easier, unless the CSV is very large, to just use two TStringLists to accomplish what you want. Here's an example (untested, because I don't have your CSV file and there's no Delphi compiler on the computer I'm using.)
procedure TOrder_import.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  SLFile, SLLine: TStringList;
  InputFile: String;
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  if order_entry.OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    SLFile := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SLFile.LoadFromFile(order_entry.OpenDialog1.FileName);
      SLLine := TStringList.Create;
      try
        ProgressBar1.Max := SLFile.Count;
        for i := 0 to SLFile.Count - 1 do
        begin
          SLLine.CommaText := SLFile[i];     
          if SLLine.Count < 89 then 
            raise Exception.CreateFmt('Not enough fields in line %d', [i]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[4]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[12]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[22]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[46]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[57]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[60]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[62]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[72]);
          Memo1.Lines.Add(ST[88]);
          ProgressBar1.StepIt;
        end;
      finally
        SLLine.Free;
      end;
    finally
      SLFile.Free;
      ShowMessage('Success!');
    end;
  end;
end;


Just on a side note: you should add ProgressBar1.Max := SLFile.Count; before the for loop so ProgressBar1.StepIt; inside the loop is meaningful (assuming ProgressBar1.Step=1).

@Remy: Good catch. I missed that omission when reading the OP's code. Thanks.

Shouldn't the Memo1.Lines.Add lines use SLLine instead of ST ?

Shouldn't the ShowMessage be outside the finally? Currently you may display "Success!" followed by an error message (if there's an error in the processing of the file).

@Heartware: I think it's fine where it is, but the question wasn't about where to properly position the ShowMessage call, so I'm not going to quibble about its placement. :-) If an error occurs and the placement of the "Success" message is an issue for the OP, they can relocate it.
